# Getting Multiple Minimum Values in an Array (When I Only Want One)

Tags: java

I'm trying to find the minimum and maximum values in an array.  The for loop used to find the max value works properly (it prints 100), however, the for loop to get the min value prints multiple numbers (95, 87, 85, 78).  I've tried changing where the System.out is placed as well as using a Method with a int return value and multiple values continue to show up.

Any help is appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int[] scores = {99, 95, 87, 100, 94, 85, 78, 84, 97, 91};
int min = scores[0];
int max = scores[0];

for (int i = 1; i < scores.length; i++) {
    if (scores[i] < min)
    {
        min = scores[i];
        System.out.println(+ min);
    }
}

for (int i = 1; i < scores.length; i++) {
    if (scores[i] > max)
    {
        max = scores[i];
        System.out.println(+ max);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you really need two for loops to get max and min?

Comment: You're printing out values before your minimum-finding loop has even finished, so what you're seeing is the progress of that loop, not just the final answer. As suggested (albeit somewhat cryptically) by one or two people here, you need to move the `System.out.println` calls out of the loops, otherwise there's a good chance you'll keep seeing multiple values printed, when you only want the value or `min` and `max` after their respective loop has finished.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be correct.

Because you're starting at a very high value already, there's only one value that's higher than *it* in the entire array.  So, you only see the code enter the `if` block once and print only once.

Because you're starting at a very high value already, there are *several* values that are lower than *it* in the entire array.  So, you see the print statement for as many times as there are lower numbers - in this case, four.

You would see *more* values printed out of your `max` finding loop if you had several values above 100 as well.

If you don't want to see the values until it's done, then don't print anything in the loop; print the values *outside* of their respective loop.

Answer (score 1):

The correct code looks like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < scores.length; i++) {
    if (scores[i] < min)
    {
        min = scores[i];
        System.out.println(+ min);
    }
}

for (int i = 1; i < scores.length; i++) {
    if (scores[i] > max)
    {
        max = scores[i];
    }
}

System.out.println(min);
System.out.println(max);
```

As you can see, I moved the print statements outside the for loop. Because because they will get executed multiple times if they are inside a loop, which is what is happening in your code. Why did `max` only get printed once then? This is just a coincidence. Since there is only one number in the input array that is bigger than the first element 99, the if statement only ran once.

Also, your two loops can be combined:

```
for (int i = 1; i < scores.length; i++) {
    if (scores[i] < min)
    {
        min = scores[i];
    }
    if (scores[i] > max)
    {
        max = scores[i];
    }
}

System.out.println(min);
System.out.println(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you included the standard output statment inside the for loop, It will print all new minimum/maximum's. You need to wait until you compare all values in the array and print the final minimum/maximum after the `for` loop.

Do it something like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int[] scores = {99, 95, 87, 100, 94, 85, 78, 84, 97, 91};
int min = scores[0];
int max = scores[0];

for (int i = 1; i < scores.length; i++) {
    if (scores[i] < min)
    {
        min = scores[i];
    }
}
 System.out.println(min);
for (int i = 1; i < scores.length; i++) {
    if (scores[i] > max)
    {
        max = scores[i];

    }
}
   System.out.println(max);
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to give an explanation as to how your code fixes the OP's problem.

Comment: I didn't include explanation .. because some of the answers  before mine had explanation but no code.

Comment: But remember that the aim of Stack Overflow is to act as a sort of Wikipedia of code solutions. You can't stop someone else editing or deleting their answers, so your own answer must stand alone as an example and explanation without relying on anything else. If you feel that the advice in your answer has been covered better by another answer, then you can delete your answer, or edit it to offer a different approach not already suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this is for a real project rather than homework, I'll suggest breaking the min and max code out into separate methods, and using the new Java 8 Streams methods to let the JDK do the work of implementing the logic.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] scores = {99, 95, 87, 100, 94, 85, 78, 84, 97, 91};
    System.out.println("Min is: "+minIntValueFromArray(scores));
    System.out.println("Max is: "+maxIntValueFromArray(scores));
}

public static int minIntValueFromArray(int[] array) {
    if (array.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Array must not be empty.");
    }
    return Arrays.stream(array).min().getAsInt();
}

public static int maxIntValueFromArray(int[] array) {
    if (array.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Array must not be empty.");
    }
    return Arrays.stream(array).max().getAsInt();
}
```

The `Arrays.stream(int[])` method (part of Java 8) creates an `IntStream` using the numbers it finds in the primitive `int` array. (It's recommended that you never create a `Stream<Integer>` when you can use an `IntStream` instead.) The `min()` and `max()` methods are provided by the Java 8 Streams API, so you don't have to worry about writing the code for these functions.

Note that `max()` and `min()` return an `OptionalInt`, because it's possible that an empty array will be encountered sometimes, thus an optional type must be returned by the stream. It's safe here to call `getAsInt()` because we've already checked to make sure that the array is not empty. An exception will be thrown if the array is empty, but how you choose to handle the empty-array case is up to you. If you wanted a specific `int` value returned in the case of an empty array then you could replace the method with something like this:

```
private static final int ARRAY_MIN_EMPTY_DEFAULT = 0;

public static int minIntValueFromArray(int[] array) {
    return Arrays.stream(array).min().orElse(ARRAY_MIN_EMPTY_DEFAULT);
}
```

Note that a lot of people are still wary of Java 8 Streams, because benchmarks claim that their performance is lower than using old iterative methods (such as your existing code). Unless your code is going to be used in performance-critical parts of an application then you should be fine either way. (And if performance is critical you should be profiling and benchmarking to work out what needs to be optimized.)

Answer (score -1):

Simply print min and max values out side of for loop.

Comment: This is correct advice, but your answer would be much more useful if you edit it to show a code snippet which clearly demonstrates exactly what you mean, and a brief explanation as to how your code solves the OP's problem.